# Where to find Index Entries on CRSP (WRDS)

Tags: finance, data-request, applied-econometrics

I am trying to find index entries (not delisting data) on CRSP (i.e., where a specific stock with a PERMNO/CUSIP enters the S&P500), but despite trawling through the documentation I am unable to find this data. Several academic (finance) papers suggest that CRSP does indeed have this data. Would anybody be so kind as to shed light on where I can find it?